# What does array_walk() do?

Tags: php, arrays, array-walk

I don't get what `array_walk($arr, 'intval');` does, which I have commented out in the following code snippet:

```
<?php    
$handle = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
fscanf($handle,"%d",$n);
$arr_temp = fgets($handle);
$arr = explode(" ",$arr_temp);
//array_walk($arr,'intval');
$sum=0;
foreach($arr as $i)
{
    $sum = $sum + $i;
}
echo $sum;
?>
```

If I use it or not does not seem to change the output.

Comment: `array_walk` recursively calls a function on each element of array. So basically `inval()` is called on every array element to get the integer value from that element.  check here:-http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php   and http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php..   you can understand more through this:- https://eval.in/657790

Comment: you can read and run the example from http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php for to learn `array_walk`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The intention of it is that it ***should*** convert every item of `$arr` to integer.

**But it does not do that!**

Note that using array_walk with `intval` is inappropriate.

There are many examples on internet that suggest to use following code to safely escape arrays of integers:

```
<?php
array_walk($arr, 'intval'); // does nothing in PHP 5.3.3
?>
```

It works in *some* older PHP versions (5.2), but it is against specifications. Since `intval()` does not modify its arguments, but returns modified result, the code above has no effect on the array.

You can use following instead:

```
<?php
$arr = array_map('intval', $arr);
?>
```

Or if you insist on using `array_walk`:

```
<?php
array_walk($arr, function(&$e) { // note the reference (&)
   $e = intval($e);
});
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[PHP's array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) function calls the specified function on every object on an array, so in the case `array_walk($arr, 'intval');` you are converting every value in the array to an integer, because that's what the [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) function does.

Comment: Since `intval()` does not modify its arguments, it has no effect on the array when used with array_walk!